# How are we considering constraints for variables in this problem?

Tags: c++, constraints

**Question: Read 3 numbers from stdin and print their sum to stdout.
Constraints: 1 <= a,b,c =< 1000.**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int x, y, z;

    cin >> x >> y >> z;
    sum = x + y + z;
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**This is working but how has 1 <= a,b,c =< 1000 been taken care of?**

Comment: What *Constraints: 1 <= a,b,c =< 1000* means is that is the constraint of the inputs into your program.  You have to make sure your code can deal with those values.

Comment: Limit allows to know which types you can/cannot use. For example, using `char` won't works with these limits. It might also indicate expected complexity.

Comment: Normally in such exercises you don't need to validate input. You can *assume* that the values will be in that range.

Comment: The "Constraints" are the limits of the *input* given to your program.

Comment: I think that you have to check that that `x`, `y` and `z` in input are greater than 1 and less than 1000, simply: if they are proceed with the sum and print it, otherwise return a warning or an error message.

Answer (score 1):

The question is saying, "no input will be less than 1 or greater than 1000".

You choose your types accordingly. For example, the maximum sum is 1000+1000+1000, so if your type (`int`) can hold that value on your platform then you're golden.

It also may mean that you can opt to forgo validation or testing for values outside of that range, though you should check with your instructor about this if it is not clear. Regardless, you may still wish to perform this validation in order to *verify* that the constraints are being upheld by whomever's passing the data. Generally, whether this is worth doing depends on the situation. For education, it seems likely that the constraints being given means "you won't need to worry about doing that". Perhaps a future assignment will then involve unconstrained inputs.

Comment: Actually, the input can be greater than 999, they can assume a value of 1000: they can not be greater than 1000.

Comment: @Eddymage You're right; I read `=<` as `<` because it's backwards. Ironically, my answer originally said 1000 before I "corrected" it ;) I've "fixed" it back.. thanks!

Comment: you're right, sometime that notation bothers me too!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you declare the data type of x,y and z as int ensures that the range of the values will be between -2147483648 to 2147483647, which is the default range of values for int(4 bytes) in C++.

Comment: `int` is not necessary 4 bytes or 32bits

Comment: _"which is the default range of values for int(4 bytes) in C++."_ This is incorrect.

Comment: Typically, on most systems, i would say it's 4 bytes. And considering he's asking it with respect to a question with constraints, it's mostly likely a question for competitive coding platform, either GeeksForGeeks,Leetcode or maybe Hackerrank and in those systems, the value for int is 4 bytes.

Comment: "Typically" is one thing. "The default" is quite another. There is no default. Also nobody mentioned "competitive coding platforms", and even if you were on one, you should not make assumptions. You will find hundreds of thousands of questions on this site from people using 16-bit `int`s, for example.

Comment: You can't count on typically.  There are people still being taught how to program C++ using DOSBox and TurboC++.  Those people only get a 16 bit int.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the a naive check in your code, controlling if each input value belongs to the interval [1,1000] and asking to insert correct values if the check fails:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int x, y, z;

    cin >> x >> y >> z;
    while(x<1 || x>1000 || y<1 || y>1000 || z<1 || z>1000){
       cout << "Error: each input value must belong to [1,1000]!" << endl;
       cin >> x >> y >> z;
    }
    sum = x + y + z;
    cout << "The sum is " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe you want instead `main` to return an error code when the input are not in the given interval:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int x, y, z;

    cin >> x >> y >> z;
    if(x<1 || x>1000 || y<1 || y>1000 || z<1 || z>1000){
       cout << "Error: each input value must belong to [1,1000]. Abort." << endl;
       return -1;
    }
    sum = x + y + z;
    cout << "The sum is " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I suggest to insert a statement with the instruction at the beginning, something like

```
cout << "Insert 3 values belonging to [1,1000]" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
     
    int a,b,c;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    int sum;
    if(a>=1 && a<=1000 && b>=1 && b<=1000 && c>=1 && c<=1000)
    {
        sum=a+b+c;
        cout<<sum<<endl;
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).